# Cannot update a component (`Categoriess`) while rendering a different component (`CellRenderer`)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am getting this warning.

Warning: Cannot update a component (`Categoriess`) while rendering a different component (`CellRenderer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render%60

I tried too much to fix this issue but I can't. Can anyone please solve this issue?
my code:

`

```
import { DrawerActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Divider, NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View
} from 'react-native';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import { API_KEY, URL } from '../../globalVariable';
const Categoriess = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [homeID, setHomeId] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const option = () => {
    let url = `${URL}/store-api/category`;
    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'sw-access-key': `${API_KEY}`,
      },
    };
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setData(!!json?.elements ? json.elements : [])
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(err => { });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    option();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View >
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}>
        <View style={styles.closeDrawer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Close Menu</Text>
          <AntDesign name='close' size={30} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}>
        Categories
      </Text>
      {
        loading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <FlatList
          data={data}
          initialNumToRender={7}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            {
              if (item.level === 1 && item.afterCategoryId === null) {
                setHomeId(item.id);
              }
            }
            const newLocal =
              item.level === 2 && item.parentId === homeID ? item.parentId : '';
            return (
              <View >
                <View>
                  <View>
                    {item.visible === true && item.parentId === newLocal ? (
                      <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Products', item)}>
                          <Text style={styles.category}>{item.name}</Text>
                          <NativeBaseProvider>
                            <Divider thickness={3} bg="red.200" />
                          </NativeBaseProvider>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        {data.map((curElem, index) => {
                          return item.id === curElem.parentId ? (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              key={index}
                              onPress={() =>
                                navigation.navigate('Products', curElem)
                              }>
                              <Text style={styles.subCategory}>
                                - {curElem.name}
                              </Text>
                              <NativeBaseProvider>
                                <Divider thickness={1} />
                              </NativeBaseProvider>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                          ) : null;
                        })
                        }
                      </View>
                    ) : null}
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      }
    </View>
  );
};

export default Categoriess;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  category: {
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    marginVertical: 5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#6779b4',
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"
  },
  subCategory: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"
  },
  closeDrawer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"
  },
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Check this part in renderItem prop. This issue often happens when you trying setState something inside render function

```
  if (item.level === 1 && item.afterCategoryId === null) {
    setHomeId(item.id);
  }
```

Looks like you shouldn't store this value in state. Just check it in every renderItem will be enough. FlatList optimisations do all other work well.

```
const homeID = item.level === 1 && item.afterCategoryId === null ? setHomeId(item.id) : null;
```

As example